# Hunting the syntactical error in Scala: x:Int=>x+2

Tags: scala

I do not follow why the following definition of a scala function does not work. Any idea?

```
scala> x:Int=>x+2
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '=>' found.
```

Comment: You need parens around `x: Int`.

Comment: Use round parentheses as a bear trap!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jubobs mentioned, you need to use the `()` around `x:Int`:

```
scala> (x: Int) => x + 2
res0: Int => Int = $$Lambda$1038/240000757@6d11ceef
```

Same as:

```
(_: Int) + 2
```

**EDIT: Added Reason and link to reference**

The reason is simply syntactic:

```
Expr            ::=  (Bindings | [`implicit'] id | `_') `=>' Expr
ResultExpr      ::=  (Bindings | ([`implicit'] id | `_') `:' CompoundType) `=>' Block
Bindings        ::=  `(' Binding {`,' Binding} `)'
Binding         ::=  (id | `_') [`:' Type]
```

source: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions